# Error while trying to call a class method: attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value) - Lua

Tags: lua, texas-instruments

I'm creating a lua script that should run on the TI-Nspire calculator. The problem is that while running my script I get the error `Attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)` when the `button:activate()` method is called. The parser says the error is in the 8th line in the code below. The problematic code is as follows:

```
button = class(view)

function button:init()
    self.selected = false
end

function button:activate()
    self.selected = true
end
```

I call the activate function like this:

```
item = button()
local action = "activate"
local arguments = {}
item[action](unpack(arguments))
```

I am aware the `class()` function doesn't exist in "stock" Lua, it's a function available in the TI-Nspire Lua implementation. You can find its definition and usage [here](http://wiki.inspired-lua.org/class%28%29).

Comment: The question title is not informative.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the title. Is this better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`obj:methodname(args)` is sugar for `obj.methodname(obj,args)`. So, if you want to use the syntax `item[action](unpack(arguments))`, you need to use `item[action](item,unpack(arguments))`. Otherwise, try `item:activate(unpack(arguments))` if you can use method explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't call the method explicitly, so I went with `item[action](item, unpack(arguments))`, but it doesn't fully solve my problem... Yes, the error message is gone, but it is replaced by a new one on the line that calls the method. The new error message is: `attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)`. Do you happen to now how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Frog, that message indicate that `action` is not the name of a method that `item` has. Perhaps a mispelling?

Comment: Indeed, action is not the method's name, it's a string which is the method's name. I'm sure there's no typing error, because the correct function was called in my original example (which called a static method). Do you have a clue what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Frog, try `print(item,action,item[action])` before the call.

Comment: I can't use `print()` (because TI doesn't show the output, only send it to the serial port), but I have just drawer the strings to the screen instead. Variable `item` was different every time, I once had: "table: 10e77440". The `action` variable was either "activate", "mousedown", "mouseup" depending on the action and finally, `item[action]` als equaled nil. I guess this means `item[action]` isn't defined. But how is that possible when I can call `item:activate()`?

Comment: @Frog try drawing `item.activate`. Does it print "function #something", or does it print nil?

Comment: Hi Kikito! Thanks for all your replies. I've fixed the problem. Thanks!