# Lua - util_server.lua:440 attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null, self

Good evening
Will you help me solve this problem?

**ERROR: race/util_server.lua:440: attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)**

```
 
function string:split(separator)
    if separator == '.' then
        separator = '%.'
    end
    local result = {}
    for part in self:gmatch('(.-)' .. separator) do
        result[#result+1] = part
    end
    result[#result+1] = self:match('.*' .. separator .. '(.*)$') or self
    return result
end
```

Comment: Which one is line 440?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while trying to call a class method: attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value) - Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353035/error-while-trying-to-call-a-class-method-attempt-to-index-local-self-a-nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably calling it wrong.

```
function string:split(separator)
```

Is short hand for:

```
function string.split(self, separator)
```

Given a string and separator:

```
 s = 'This is a test'
 separator = ' '
```

You need to call it like this:

```
 string.split(s, separator)
```

Or:

```
 s:split(separator)
```

If you call it like this:

```
 s.split(separator)
```

You're failing to provide a value for the `self` argument.

---

Side note, you can write `split` more simply like this:

```
function string:split(separators)
    local result = {}
    for part in self:gmatch('[^'..separators..']+') do
        result[#result + 1] = part
    end
    return result
end
```

This has the disadvantage that you can't used multi-character strings as delimiters, but the *advantage* that you can specify more than one delimiter. For instance, you could strip all the punctuation from a sentence and grab just the words:

```
s = 'This is an example: homemade, freshly-baked pies are delicious!'
for _,word in pairs(s:split(' :.,!-')) do
    print(word)
end
```

Output:

```
This
is
an
example
homemade
freshly
baked
pies
are
delicious
```

Comment: one note. in call `s.split(sep)` `self` is `sep` so it is not nil(if sep is not nil)